# Pass QGeoCoordinate from c++ to qml

Tags: qt, qml

Is there any "good" way to do this? The only solution I found so far is to use a QVariantList of double's, but it is relatively slow (10 million points ~ 1second on Core i3) and ugly...

Comment: I think it's not good way as a whole - passing 10 million points. It means that most of them will not be visible. So you need some optimization here. As for your question - may be some C++ function witch returns coordinate object(or double value) by index? At least you can save a time here at conversion to `QVariant` and back ...

Comment: Thank you very much! that solves both problems...

Comment: You should put an answer to your question that describe your solution for others who may see this.

Comment: You should mark the following answer as a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One good way to pass QGeoCoordinate (but might not scale to 10 million well, have not stress tested this) back and forth through qml/c++ is to use the following

```
//when passsing from c++, qml will see the below as a coordinate type
QVariant::fromValue(yourQGeoCoordinateObjectHere);

//when passing coordinate from qml, the below will give you a 
//QGeoCoordinate object to work with
returnedQVariantObject.value<QGeoCoordinate>();
```